# "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array" for int[][] var = new int[m][n]

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I'm getting this weird exception report from other users:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array
    at yuku.alkitab.base.util.Levenshtein.distance(Levenshtein.java:16)
```

The relevant snippet is:

```
private static final int deletion = 500;

public static int distance(String s, String t) {
    // d is a table with m+1 rows and n+1 columns
    int m = s.length();
    int n = t.length();

    int[][] d = new int[m + 1][n + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        d[i][0] = i * deletion; // <------ this is line 16
    }

    // more lines omitted
}
```

Examining the above code I could not find out how that exception can ever happened. Did I miss something?

All crash reports came from Android 6.0, API 23.

Comment: at which i did it crash could you possibly know or its random is it regenerated always on android 6.0 API 23

Comment: Unable to reproduce. What values of `s` and `t` cause this error? Looking at the code, I cannot see any way for that error to occur. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We can't be sure until you post proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is good thing that you want to minimize your example but with current code we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: deletion is an int, you have a bidimensional array, s and t pass untill line 16, and that means that m and n have an int value...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in my machine, that's why I don't know the values of `s` and `t` that possibly causes the error. Looking at the code, I can't see any way for the error to occur, but I might miss something, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: In that specific line I really don't see how you would get a null pointer. A sort of array out of bounds exception maybe, but a null pointer seems impossible.

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha I agree. AFAIK, a multidimensional primitive array initialized in that way should not have `null`. Unless I miss something.

Comment: A single crash report shows me this: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0  at yuku.alkitab.base.util.Levenshtein.distance(Levenshtein.java:16)` (same line as above)
which looks even weirder (array length == 0). Is it quite safe now to say that this is a bug on the Android Runtime (ART)?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information to the question. Currently the only thing that should make the code not work, is that it is not returning the value it should return (int).